# Tweak the definition of filter in textbook Introduction to Set Theory 3rd by Hrbacek and Jech

Tags: definition, filters

My textbook Introduction to Set Theory 3rd by Hrbacek and Jech defines *filter* as follows:

> **1.1 Definition** Let $S$ be a nonempty set. A *filter* on $S$ is a collection $\mathcal F$ of subsets of $S$ that satisfies the following conditions:
>
> (a) $S \in \mathcal F$ and $\emptyset \notin \mathcal F$.
>
> (b) If $X \in \mathcal F$ and $Y \in \mathcal F$, then $X \cap Y \in \mathcal F$.
>
> (c) If $X \in \mathcal F$ and $X \subseteq Y \subseteq S$, then $Y \in \mathcal F$.

I found that we can omit the criteria $S \in \mathcal F$ by adding another one $\mathcal F \neq \emptyset$.

- $S \in \mathcal F \implies \mathcal F \neq \emptyset$
- $\mathcal F \neq \emptyset \implies \exists X \in \mathcal F$. On the other hand, $X \subseteq S$. Then $S \in \mathcal F$.

Please confirm if my reasoning is correct or not! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, since it’s closed under supersets, if it’s nonempty, then it contains $S.$ (And of course conversely if it contains $S$ then it is nonempty.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct of course. You could reformulate (without (a)) as:

> "A filter on $S$ is a non-empty collection $\mathcal{F}$ from $\mathscr{P}(S)\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ such that (b) and (c) hold.

But that sort of "hides" a point and didactically they maybe wanted to stress explicitly that $S \in \mathcal{F}$ and also $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$; it'a textbook after all, not a treatise striving for minimal definitions.
It's more "concrete" in the way the state it. Also it hints to the minimal filter on $S$: $\{S\}$.